# How to access nested elements in xml with OpenXML

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008-r2, openxml, xml-import

I'm trying to import data from a rather large xml file to an SQL Server. After some online searching I settled upon using OpenXML. The query I have so far is

```
DECLARE @doc INT
DECLARE @xml XML
SELECT @xml = evnt
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'c:\archive.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS Import(evnt)

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @doc OUTPUT, @xml

SELECT *
FROM OPENXML( @doc, '/Events/eventData/event', 2)
WITH (
  id varchar(max)
)
EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @doc
```

In this way I'm able to get elements listed inside 'event', but how would I get an element one more level down from 'event'.
For example how would I get the 'CustId' tag below?

```
<event>
    <custromAttribute>
        <CustId>...
```

The items inside 'event' is mainly needed hence the path cant be changed. 
Also any other approaches would be nice too. I need it to run from SQL Server so can't use SSIS or other similar external tools. 
XQuery seems to take a lot of time.

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: Why did you choose OpenXML instead of the native SQL Server XQuery support? Seems a lot easier to use and more flexible...

Comment: I read in a lot of places that OpenXML is better with larger files, though it is very memory intensive. The files to be parsed can easily go over 100MB.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is interested the solution to the above question was simple enough.

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENXML( @doc, '/Events/eventData/event')
WITH (
  ID varchar(max) 'id'
  CustID varchar(20) 'customAttribute/CustId',
  AttributeID varchar(20) '@id'
  SampleID varhcar(20) 'Ele1/Ele2[3]/id'
)
```

The values in quotes should match the name in the xml doc exactly. '@' is used to select attributes in the element. Going back a level is done with '../'.

The SampleID fetches 'id' within the third 'Ele2' element inside 'Ele1'